# Max() throwing error in command prompt but not IDLE

Tags: python, batch-file, glob

I'm not sure why but I'm consistently getting an error on a Python script run through a batch file, but no error when run through IDLE. It keeps failing on this line:

```
png_files = glob.glob("X:\\Projects\\Integration\\PNGs\\*.png")
latest_png = max(png_files, key = os.path.getctime)
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\A\Documents\PYTHON\Data.py", line 460, in <module>
        latest_png = max(png_files, key = os.path.getctime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

If I run just these lines by themselves in IDLE, they return the latest PNG without an issue. But in the script it is consistently failing but *only* when it is run through a batch file.

Comment: Do you run your IDLE as administrator?

Comment: Not innately no. The batch file, however, is run as admin.

Comment: With UAC enabled, the system logs on an administrator account with two tokens, the restricted token and the elevated token that a service can use to created an elevated process. Each token has its own logon session and security context, so naturally each has its own set of DOS device mappings. Thus a mapped network drive "X:" created by Explorer in the context of the restricted token is not visible to an elevated process -- at least not by default.

Comment: There's a policy you can set to link session DOS devices between these two logons. Create a new `DWORD` named `EnableLinkedConnections` with a value of 1 in the key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`. Restart the system.

Comment: Just a quick update, I've discovered that the issue is a permissions problem. In Python in CMD my `os.access()` is `False` to the Network Drive letter, but `True` to the UNC path. Is there a reason this might be? I've contacted IT and they've assured me there were no permission changes.

Comment: As I explained above, the drive probably doesn't exist for elevated processes. Run an elevated command prompt and enter `net use`. Do you see drive "X:" listed as an *accessible* drive?

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing any drives there... Is there a way to change this?

Comment: My second comment explained a way to link mapped drives for a linked logon. Configure the policy that implements this and restart the system.

Answer (score 1):

There are no elements in `png_files`. Make sure that your glob call has permission to look in that directory, there are files in that directory, and that the directory exists.

Comment: I've checked and double checked this. I have full access to the location. The batch file is also being run as administrator so it shouldn't encounter any issues. In fact I've got a duplicate script that checks the same location and it works fine. The only difference is that in this script I upload whatever PNG it finds to a website.

Comment: @ATCH_torn what is the result when you `print(png_files)`?

Comment: There's over 100 files in there so I just did `print(png_files[:2])` but the result I got was: `['X:\\Projects\\Integration\\PNGs\\07102017  06.png', 'X:\\Projects\\Integration\\PNGs\\07112017  02.png']`

Comment: Hm. I can't reproduce it. I'm getting a result and no exception when I try it.

Comment: It makes no sense to me why it would be producing this error. It works absolutely fine if I run the script through IDLE but always throws this error when run through a .bat...

Comment: Can you paste the entire batch file somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149400/discussion-between-atch-torn-and-thomas-ross).